# Angular directive to hide 'grandparent' of element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been using the following code to hide the 'grandparent' of any '404' images on my page and it works well:

```
function imgError(image){
  image.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}

<img ng-src="{{photo.img}}" onerror="imgError(this);" id="image">
```

I want to move this functionality into a custom Angular directive and the below is my current implementation, but it does not work. I think my issue lies in incorrectly grabbing the image's 'grandparent' element.

**Directive:**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('hideImage', hideImage);

function hideImage() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('error', function() {
      angular.element(this).parent().parent().attr('style', attrs.hideImage);
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in event.photos">
  <a ng-href="{{photo.link}}" target="_blank" title="{{photo.text}}">
    <img ng-src="{{photo.img}}" hide-image="'display: none;'" id="image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: just curious: did you try to remove the single quotes from your `hide-image` attribute?

Comment: I'm going to give it a try when I get a chance. Thanks, I think that should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `angular.element(this)` here because you already have control over element using `element` parameter of link function, You should be using jQLite `.css` function rather than using JavaScript.

```
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('error', function() {
      element.parent().parent().css({'display': 'none'}); //you can pass that css from attribute
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems backwards to me...and that you should not show anything until image is confirmed loaded

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in event.photos" image-wrapper ng-show="imageLoaded">
  <a ng-href="{{photo.link}}">
    <img ng-src="{{photo.img}}">
  </a>
</div>
```

Directive on main element now using `ng-show` which will only show after image load has occurred. The scope variable will initially be undefined, and use `onload` event of image to set it to true

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('imageWrapper', imageLoader);

function imageLoader() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.find('img')[0].onload=function(){ 
       scope.$apply(function(){ // use $apply for all events outside of angular
          scope.imageLoaded=true;
       })
    })
  }
}
```

Also note you can't repeat ID's in a page

Comment: if any of the image gets an error then all element will get hidden

Comment: @pankajparkar no because `ng-repeat` creates child scopes, that variable will be local to each child scope only

Comment: yes but you are setting `imageLoaded` scope variable outside of `ng-repeat` & you have not created it any where in `ng-repeat`

Comment: @pankajparkar  ok..you are right..not sure what I was thinking. Would need an extra inner element to put that on to bring it into the child scope

Comment: that is what i was trying to say..your approach is never gonna work.

Answer (score 1):

```
hide-image="'display: none;'"
```

should be

```
hide-image="display: none;"
```

(no single quotes)